# 1 app handling all NFC request, or lots of apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, android-permissions

I am currently developing some very basic apps for Android devices that utilise NFC stickers.  A sticker is scanned and the device carries out a simple action.  An example of this may be to call a certain number (held in the payload of the NFC sticker).

My original plan was to make an app for each action, as each of my customers will probably only have one NFC sticker.  So, if someone wants to buy a sticker to call 999/911 (this is a fictitious example) then they only need the app that dials the number.

However, I will be pushing to sell other stickers, and I don't want to flood somebody's device with tiny apps when I can easily control it all from the one app.  Let's say I have 5 stickers that: toggle wi-fi, toggle bluetooth, dial 999, SMS home, call a taxi.  Those would all require the following permissions:

- Bluetooth
- Bluetooth admin
- Wi-fi admin
- Make calls
- SMS

If I only bought the bluetooth sticker then I may become suspicious of why the app wants to make calls or send SMS messages.

My question is, what would be the correct approach here?

- Lots of apps doing simple tasks and potentially annoy customers with multiple stickers (there will potentially be a lot of people with multiple stickers).  Or,
- One app that reads the payload of the NFC sticker and does the relevant action, but requests all of the needed permissions for all NFC stickers available (could be potentially dosens of unneeded permissions for an individual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am opting for one app, purely for ease of use.  If app size becomes an issue it will be split into multiple apps.

To get around the permissions issue there will be a well-written description explaining the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off with one app that read all your tags and take action.  Few people are going to be willing to download 5 apps after purchasing 5 tags from you.

If you're worried about permissions, take a look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher and its permissions and rating.  It's doing quite well.

Comment: I agree that has some excellent ratings, but you would expect that app to request all permissions, given that it is a tool to write to the tags, so the user is expecting to give almost global permissions. My dilemma is that the user may only be expecting (for example) to give permissions to turn bluetooth on - they won't have any clue that the app is capable of doing countless other tasks depending on the sticker scanned.

Answer (score 0):

"Lots of apps" , a lot of nfc apps enabled as default?
Your customers will probably not only tap your tags, but also tap other things. Which app will open?

Suggestion to make an app more secure; make an extra step to ask always user confirmation. This is about security vs convenience. Customers will not want/need an extra step for their home-made tags. Bur more and more smart posters/tags will appear in the wild.

Comment: NFC tags don't work in that way, at least not the ones I sell.  My stickers open the app I have set in the payload, other apps will not interfere in any way.  The user can use any other NFC tag/sticker in the world and it will never open my app(s).